# How to get instance of prototype bean in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, singleton

In Spring, if I define a prototype bean, I can inject it using [lookup method injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection) at the current time of Spring Framework 4.3.0.RELEASE.

In Grails, how do I inject a prototype bean at runtime? [Grails 2.5.4 docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/spring.html) show how to set `bean.scope = 'prototype"` and `bean.singleton = false` but does not actually give an example of how to inject a non-singleton bean.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen much use of prototype-scope beans in Grails, and what I've seen uses the pattern described in the Spring docs that works directly with the ApplicationContext. I assume that you could use the same method injection approach in Grails that you use in Spring, but here's a simple factory class that doesn't involve CGLIB subclassing but is otherwise similar. It does retrieve a prototype instance from the ApplicationContext, but that's hidden in the implementation and doesn't clutter your application code:

```
package com.yourcompany

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware

@CompileStatic
class PrototypeFactory<T> implements ApplicationContextAware {

   ApplicationContext applicationContext
   final Class<T> beanClass
   final String beanName

   PrototypeFactory(Class<T> beanClass, String beanName) {
      this.beanClass = beanClass
      this.beanName = beanName
   }

   T getInstance() {
      applicationContext.getBean(beanName, beanClass)
   }
}
```

To use it, register a bean for the class, providing the bean name and bean class of the prototype bean (in resources.groovy, or in a plugin's doWithSpring):

```
beans = {
   cartFactory(PrototypeFactory, ShoppingCart, 'shoppingCart')
}
```

Now you can inject the factory bean and call `getInstance()`, and it will return a new prototype instance, and since it's using generics you don't need any casts:

```
class SomeClass {
   PrototypeFactory<ShoppingCart> cartFactory
   ...

   def someMethod() {
      ShoppingCart newCart = cartFactory.instance
      ...
   }
}
```

You can reuse the factory class to register as many of these as you want for various prototype beans as long as they have unique bean names.

None of the names are significant, so change `getInstance()` to whatever you prefer, and change 'Factory' to 'Manager' or whatever.